# Ubuntu make Intel HD primary display in xorg.conf

Tags: nvidia, intel-graphics, xorg.conf

I have a mining rig with 10 GPU on it. It's all running fine except when I'd like to use the Intel HD graphic for display and GPUs for computing.

In my xorg.conf file everything works when I boot with this:

```
Section "ServerLayout"
Identifier "layout"
Screen 0 "screen 0" 
Screen 1 "screen 1"
Screen X "screen x"
...etc...
```

for each GPU I have a device section and a screen section corresponding to all screens displayed above. I have a separated device and screen section for the intel HD but it's not associated to any of those screens.

When I try to set the intel HD as primary display, the machine boots up to a login screen and each time I enter my login, it asks my login again and so on.

To achieve this I have simply assigned screen 0 to intel like this

```
Screen 0 "intel"
Screen 1 "screen1" 0 0 
...etc for all other GPUs...

Section "Device"
Identifier "intel"
Driver "intel"
BusID "PCI:0@0:2:0"
Option "AccelMethod" "sna"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
Identifier "intel"
Device "intel"
EndSection
```

I'm doing this exactly the same way as for the GPU but it doesn't work. Should I use a different configuration in xorg.conf?

Thanks!